# Heat kernel expression for index calculation/Nakahara Exercise 12.5

Tags: operators, integration, topology

A quick question. I was reading this [paper](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.16.1052), on the last page, the authors wrote
$$
\lim_{\mu^2\rightarrow\infty} \text{Tr} \int_0^\infty dT\ e^{-T} \Big(e^{-(T/\mu^2)LL^\dagger}-e^{-(T/\mu^2)L^\dagger L}\Big) = \lim_{t\rightarrow0}\text{Tr} \Big(e^{-tLL^\dagger}-e^{-tL^\dagger L}\Big).
$$
Anyone has any ideas how to show this equality? I do believe the formula is correct because something very similar showed up in Nakahara's topology book, in Exercise 12.5 (equation 12.110) on page 475 in the second edition I own, where he said the index of a two-term complex can be written as $\text{Tr}\big(\frac{s}{\Delta_E+s}-\frac{s}{\Delta_F+s}\big) $ for arbitrary $s$, which is what one gets by performing the above integration. But he did not include a derivation either.

Answer (score 1):

If $\lambda>0$ is an eigenvalue of  $L^\dagger L$ with associated eigenfunction $u$, the then $Lu$  is an eigenfunction  of  $L L^\dagger$ with the same eigenvalue.   As a consequence,  in each of these expressions  the contributions of the non-zero eigenvalues cancel in pairs. Only the zero modes contribute to give
$$
{\rm Index}= {\rm dimKer}[L L^\dagger]- {\rm dimKer}[L^\dagger L].
$$
This assumes that the manifold is compact and the eigenvalues discrete.  There can be corrections when the manifold is open.